# FlxSpriteGroup is not visible (haxeflixel)

Tags: macos, graphics, haxe, haxeflixel

I'm trying to create some sort of "item displayer" in a game to showcase items or act as an icon in the inventory (it will include informations like item tier, item name, exc).

To achieve this, i wanted to create a `ItemDisplay` class extending `FlxSpriteGroup`, and put inside it the frame, background and info for the item as `Sprites`, so that i would be able to work with all as if they were a single `Sprite`.

So i did just that, but the group isn't showing up when the `ItemDisplay` object is created and supposedly `add`ed to the `FlxState`.

After some troubleshooting, i discovered that the object `exists`, but `isOnScreen()` returns `false`, and i don't know why.

Here's the code i'm using to create the `ItemDisplay` object:

```
        var itd:ItemDisplay = new ItemDisplay(FlxG.width / 2, FlxG.height / 2, test_sword);
        add(itd);
```

...and here's the `ItemDisplay` class in all it's glory:

```
class ItemDisplay extends FlxSpriteGroup
{
    override public function new(posX:Float, posY:Float, itemToShow:Item)
    {
        super();
        x = posX;
        y = posY;

        // create sprites
        var bckgr:FlxSprite = new FlxSprite(x, y);
        var itPng:FlxSprite = new FlxSprite(x, y);
        var itFrm:FlxSprite = new FlxSprite(x, y);

        // load sprites graphics (problem's not here, i checked)
        bckgr.loadGraphic("assets/images/ui/item_framing/ifbg_" + itemToShow.tier + "Tier.png");
        itPng.loadGraphic(itemToShow.pngPath);
        itFrm.loadGraphic("assets/images/ui/item_framing/item_frame.png");

        // add all sprites to group
        this.add(bckgr);
        this.add(itPng);
        this.add(itFrm);
    }
}
```

(i'm running the code on **macos**, not HTML5)

If you have any idea why the `ItemDisplay` is not showing up, please explain it to me, as i'm not that good of a programmer, and i might have missed something.
Thank you ^-^

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, as i thought, it was my stupid error: when creating the sprites in lines 10-12, i set their positions to `X` and `Y`, to make them the same as the group positions.

I just found out that the sprites consider the group's x and y as (0, 0), and start calculating their position from there.

So, by setting the sprites' x/y the same as the group's, i was essentially doubling the values, and putting the sprites outside of the screen

lmao sorry for bad english